# Is there any way to execute a statement before each return statement in python function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example i have this piece of code:

```
def example():
    a = 'goodbye'
    if True:
        print a
        return 1
    else:
        print a
        return 0
```

I would like to know if there is any possible solution to write once "print a" and execute it before each "return" statement automaticaly. So that if I add more return statements I wouldn't need to add anything, but "print a" would execute. Result would look like something:

```
def example():
    a = "goodbye"
    """ some code to implement print a """
    if True:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Each time there is return statement it still would print a.

I tried to google, but don't know how word query, since all results are about returning multiple values.

**UPDATE**: My question was answered, thanks to all of you.
Although wrapping functions are correct answer, but I have chosen answer by [GingerPlusPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35338102/3842800) who suggested to use `try...finally` for simplicity.

Comment: Can't you rewrite it to have only a single return statement?

Comment: `print a` before `if and else` loop?.

Comment: Just use `print` inside the method. Once you execute the `method` you would get the output from the `print` statement.

Comment: If you wrap the technique in Didier's answer below in a decorator then you should get what you want: logging exit points without having to insert the tracing code manually.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`try .. finally`:

```
def example():
    try:
       if True:
           return 1
       else:
           return 0
    finally:
        print 'goodbye'

>>> example()
goodbye
1
```

> A *finally* clause is always executed before leaving the `try` statement, whether an exception has occurred or not. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)

Comment: One caveat; per your example, the `finally:` clause is executed before the `try:` clause.  In the case of printing a string, it's probably irrelevant, but if order matters for more complex functions, proceed with caution.

Comment: @pshep123: [Not really](http://rextester.com/WBUF54319). Code in the `finally` runs after `try`, just the return value is printed only after function returns.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a context. Initialize it with the value you want to print. Then print when context exit, i.e. upon return.

```
class PrinterOnContextExit():
    def __init__( self, a ): self.a = a
    def __enter__( self ): pass
    def __exit__( self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback ): print( self.a )

def example():
    a = 'goodbye'
    with PrinterOnContextExit( a ):
        if True:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Note that you cannot print the returned value this way. If you ever wanted to print the returned value, then you should use a decorator.

```
class PrintOnReturn():
    def __init__( self, a ): self.a = a
    def __call__( self, func ): return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.callFunc( func, *args, **kwargs )
    def callFunc( self, func, *args, **kwargs ): r = func( *args, **kwargs ); print( self.a, r ); return r

@PrintOnReturn( "hello" )
def example():
    if True:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

This will print whatever string you passed to the decorator, followed by the value returned from the decorated function. Here `hello 1`.

Comment: This is best way to print something while returning from function

Comment: @didier-trosset thanks for answering! I would add break lines to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a decorator, if it suits your case:

```
>>> def decorator(text):
...     def wrapped(func):
...         def inner(*args, **kwargs):
...             result = func(*args, **kwargs)
...             print text
...             return result
...         return inner
...     return wrapped
... 

>>> @decorator('goodbye')
... def example():
...     return True
... 

>>> example()
goodbye
>>> True
```

Decorator will allow you to print any text after the decorated function was called. Or before.

Answer (score 3):

**Code:**

```
def example():
    a = 'goodbye'
    print a
    if True:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

If you `print a` before `if else` then it will print value every time you call the function.

Comment: try to add more details then just code. you will get more upvotes then.

Answer (score 2):

Create a value `returnval`

```
returnval = 0  #default value
testval = 0 # Code to set up if
# code to set various values of testval
if testval == 0:
    returnval = 1
elif testval == 5:
    returnval = 2
else:
    returnval = 10

print a
return returnval
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Def example():
a = 'goodbye'
if True:
return 1,str(a)
    else:
     return 0,str(a)
print example()
```

Thats the only way...I dont think there is a way to avoid typing what you want to be printed...sorry mate! expect if you type a function type the thinks you

Comment: type the things you want to be executed and calll it inside your example function....anyway good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

An easier alternative as i've also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793114/5736792) for a similar topic:

```
def master_example():
    a = []
    def example():
        a.append('goodbye')
        if True:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    example()
    print a[0]
```