# Function Not Printing Desired Output

Tags: python, function, tuples

I am having issues with creating a function that takes a list of tuples and then returns one string which is the first character of each tuple. Below is my current code, but nothing it happening, I do not get a syntax error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
lst_of_tups = ([('hello', 'all'), ('music', 'playing'), ('celebration', 'station')])

def build_string(lst_of_tups):
     final_str = ""
     for tup in list_of_tups:
          for item in tup:
               final_str = final_str + item[0]
     return final_str
     print build_string
```

**** expected output: hampcs****

Comment: You are returning from your fucntion, so execution never reaches the next line.

Comment: Fix the typo: `list_of_tups` vs `lst_of_tups`. It works for me once I do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to do more work after a return statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604699/is-there-a-way-to-do-more-work-after-a-return-statement)

Comment: Do you ever actually call `build_string()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those string manipulation functions are error-prone: they define lots of variables, can `return` within inner loops, have unexpected side-effects...

Once you're used to list comprehensions, you can create such programs easily & with great execution performance (string concatenation is slow). One way:

```
def build_string(lst_of_tups):
   return "".join([x[0] for y in lst_of_tups for x in y])
```

basically, it's just 2 loops (flattening the data) within a list comprehension to extract each first character from every string, joined together using `str.join` to rebuild the string.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help and yes using list comprehensions is way more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Once you reach a `return` statement in a function, the function ends for good. The line

```
print build_string
```

cannot be reached. (Another problem is that the name `build_string` is not defined.)

Use your function like this:

```
result = build_string(lst_of_tups) # calls your function and puts the return value in the result variable
print result # print the result
```

Of course, the intermediary variable `result` is not necessary, you could just issue `print build_string(lst_of_tups)` as well.