# time.sleep function isnt working in kivy app

Tags: python, kivy

I have here a simple app that displays the current bitcoin price:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
import requests 
import time 


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        while True:
            
            url = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd").json()
            price = url['bitcoin']['usd']
            return Label(text="Bitcoin Price\n " + str(price) + " USD", font_size=72)
            time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

When i run this app it works, however according to the coingecko api, they update the price every 120 seconds but the price in my app never updates.

I tried to set the time to 120 seconds 10 seconds 30 seconds etc but my price doesnt update after running.
And i dont get any error when running the problem so i dont know what the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `time.sleep()` is not advisable for GUI programs as it will make the GUI unresponsive. Instead use the [`Clock.schedule_interval()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) provided by kivy

Here is the corrected code

```
import kivy
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
import requests 
from kivy.clock import Clock
 

class MyApp(App):

    def update_price(self, lbl):
        url = requests.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd").json()
        price = url['bitcoin']['usd']

        lbl.text = "Bitcoin Price\n " + str(price) + " USD"

    def build(self):
            
        lbl = Label(font_size=72)
        # self.update_price(lbl)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda _:self.update_price(lbl), 1) # updates every 1 second

        return lbl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: it runs but the problem i have doing it this way is, if i set the time to 120seconds, the first time it prints the price is after 120 seconds, so basically the app is idle for 120 seconds, thatswhy i used the time.sleep function

Comment: @joeblow Can you explain more about what you want? If you use `time.sleep` the GUI will freeze for 120 seconds and will not accept any events for that time period. It can also completely stop or crash you app.

Comment: When the app loads i wna tto  display the "Bitcoin" price right away and than every 120 seconds it does the api call for an updated price. When i set it to 1 second, the text almost loads immediatly but when i set the price to hit every 120 seconds the user would neeed to wait 120 seconds before the price is displayed the dfirst time

Comment: yes, right now it says 1, but when i change it to 120 my app starts than there is nothing for 120 seconfds and than the price displays on the screen of the app

Answer (score 1):

You return from `build()` in your `while True` loop.

That's where it stops: It will  create and return a `Label` object once and then finish. The line `time.sleep(10)` will never be reached.

Edit for clarification: TO didn't ask for a solution, but for an explanation of the behaviour.

Comment: Not sure how "fish" slipped into there. Anyways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604699/is-there-a-way-to-do-more-work-after-a-return-statement

Comment: This kind of behavior isn't what we need here, joe. I have flagged your comment.